# After upgrading to Ubuntu-20.04.3 LTS OS rented VPS I can't reach the login screen without going into recovery mode

Tags: boot, grub2, upgrade, login

I recently rent a VPS with OS ubuntu-18.04-x86_64 LTS already installed. Then I tried to upgrade the OS to ubuntu-20.04.3 LTS, using the `do-release-upgrade` command.

After finishing the installation, and trying to reboot, it's getting stuck on the black welcome screen of Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.

[image: "Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS!" further boot/init messages follow]

I try to reboot the VPS, and press the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key up until **GNU GRUB version 2.02** black screen shows up, with 2 options : **Ubuntu** & **Advanced options for Ubuntu**.

Choosing the advanced options will bring me to another 4 options :

- Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-81-generic
- Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-81-generic (recovery mode)
- Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-154-generic
- Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-154-generic (recovery mode)

After several times of trying, I ended up to choose the **Recovery Mode**, choose the **resume** or **root** options from the **Recovery Menu**, in order to get to the login screen.

I happened to notice the message `sh: O: Can't open /virt/swfix.sh` right before the login screen shows up.

Can anyone help me to solve this issue, so that the system can reboot normally and directly to the login screen without having to choose Recovery Mode? I'm a newbie in Linux.

Thanks,
Yos.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on my VPS, but if I press `Alt` + `F1` (or any other function key), I can reach the login screen.